# Does a PDA need to sign this instruction handler?

Tags: anchor, solana-program

I am trying to learn Anchor with this tutorial https://www.soldev.app/course/intro-to-anchor-frontend, currently reading about IDL and I have some questions regarding how some accounts are declared as input parameters:

```
{
      "name": "initialize",
      "accounts": [
        { "name": "counter", "isMut": true, "isSigner": true },
        { "name": "user", "isMut": true, "isSigner": true },
        { "name": "systemProgram", "isMut": false, "isSigner": false }
      ],
      "args": []
    }
```

Why is the `counter` account's field `isSigner` true? I would think that only the payer `user` needs to sign the transaction.

```
    {
      "name": "increment",
      "accounts": [
        { "name": "counter", "isMut": true, "isSigner": false },
        { "name": "user", "isMut": false, "isSigner": true }
      ],
      "args": []
    }
```

Why is the `user` account's field `isMut` false? I thought since as the payer its balance, i.e. state, changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an error in the course. You are right the counter should not be a signer. Since it is a PDA the program will be able to change it, no matter if it is a signer or not. I will try to contact the course owner.

User needs to be mutable because they is also the fee payer. So the 5000 lamports for paying for the transactions are subtracted from his balance.